# 'NoneType' object is not iterable error using udf on ArrayType in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with following schema

```
hello.printSchema()
root
 |-- list_a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- list_b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

and following sample data

```
hello.take(2)
[Row(list_a=[7, 11, 1, 14, 13, 15,999], list_b=[15, 13, 7, 11, 1, 14]),
 Row(list_a=[7, 11, 1, 14, 13, 15], list_b=[11, 1, 7, 14, 15, 13, 12])]
```

Desired output

1. Sort `list_a` and `list_b`
2. Create a new column `list_diff` such that `list_diff = list(set(list_a) - set(list_b))` Empty ArrayType if no such difference is present.

The approach I have tried is UDF.

As mentioned in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973778/comparing-two-arrays-and-getting-the-difference-in-pyspark), I am trying to use following UDFs

```
sort_udf=udf(lambda x: sorted(x), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
differencer=udf(lambda x,y: [elt for elt in x if elt not in y], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Looks like python list operations are not supported.

```
hello = hello.withColumn('sorted', sort_udf(hello.list_a))
hello = hello.withColumn('difference', differencer(hello.list_a, hello.list_b))
```

The above operation result in following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Redacted Stack Trace]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: My bad for the wrong paste. It should be `ArrayType(IntegerType())` and not `ArrayType(StringType())`

Comment: And for sorting the list, you don't need to use a `udf` - you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array`

Comment: Yup the default function `pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array` works well.
just a small change in sorted udf `sort_udf=udf(lambda x: sorted(x) if x else None, ArrayType(IntegerType())` and it works too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message:

> `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Is a python exception (as opposed to a spark error), which means your code is failing inside your `udf`. Your issue is that you have some `null` values in your DataFrame. So when you call your `udf`, you may be passing `None` values to `sorted`:

```python
>>> sorted(None)
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-edb1060f46c4> in <module>()
----> 1 sorted(None)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The way around this is to make your `udf` robust to bad inputs. In your case, you can change your functions to handle `null` inputs like this:

```python
# return None if input is None
sort_udf = udf(lambda x: sorted(x) if x is not None else None, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

# return None if either x or y are None
differencer = udf(
    lambda x,y: [e for e in x if e not in y] if x is not None and y is not None else None,
    ArrayType(IntegerType())
)
```

However, the `sort_udf` function is not necessary, as you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array) instead.